# Get Middlewares for a Route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I want to make an unit test in phpunit where I test if a specific route does not have any middleware, since it's a requirement for that route.

Is it possible to get a list os middlewares for a route using, for example, the Route or Route collection classes?

Comment: if you have the Route you can call `middleware` or `gatherMiddleware` to get the middleware but something like the 'web' group will just come up with 'web', not all the middleware in that group

Comment: Adding to lagbox's comment, something like `Route::getRoutes()->get()[0]->computedMiddleware`. If you iterate over `foreach(Route::getRoutes()->get() as $route)`, you can check the methods available for the `Route` class and see if you have what you need: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$route->gatherMiddleware();
```